# JOIN - Get one full table and the rest of another

Tags: sql, oracle, join

Hi guys here is my Schema: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/82771

```
CREATE TABLE t1
(
Age INT,
 Name VARCHAR(20)
);

CREATE TABLE t2
(
 Age INT,
 Name VARCHAR(20)
);

INSERT INTO t1(Age, Name) VALUES(31, NULL);
INSERT INTO t1(Age, Name) VALUES(32, NULL);
INSERT INTO t1(Age, Name) VALUES(33, NULL);
INSERT INTO t1(Age, Name) VALUES(34, NULL);

INSERT INTO t2(Age, Name) VALUES(31, 'Panos');
```

I need a Join query that will give me this Result:

```
Age    Name
31    'Panos'
32     Null
33     Null
34     Null
```

I've tried LEFT JOIN and RIGHT JOIN on Age but I can't get what I need. It should be pretty simple but its just not coming to me...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way is to use union all and then check for non-existence in the second table:

```
select *
from t1
union all
select *
from t2
where Not exists (select 1 from t1 where t1.age = t2.age)
```

Comment: This answer covers me better in my real case (i just gave you guys a simplified schema here). Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

maybe you have missed something when you are doing `LEFT JOIN`. Use also coalesce to return the first *non-null* value.

```
SELECT  t1.Age, COALESCE(t2.name, t1.Name) Name
FROM    t1 
        LEFT JOIN t2
            ON t1.Age = t2.Age
```

- [SQLFiddle Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/82771/7)

Comment: Thank you for the nice quick answer. +1 for you but I will accept Gordon Linoff's answer since if fits better in my real case data. Like i said in the title I want All records from one of the tables in this case t2 and then any data from t1 that are not on t2 as well...For example if I had Null on table 2 and a Non-Null on t1 I would still want the Null from t2 (your query would give me the value of t1 since it's looking for the non nulls).